# How to browse pandas dataframe using row number eand column number

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to browse my `DF` doing :

```
for row in range(len(DF)):
    for col in range(len(DF.columns)):
        print(DF[row][col])
```

but doing so throw :

```
KeyError: 0
```

I am wondering, how to browse a whole dataframe (including col name and excluding index) using only col number and row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need select values by indices use [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)/ [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
for row in range(len(DF)):
    for col in range(len(DF.columns)):
        print(DF.iat[row, col])
        #print(DF.iloc[row, col])
```

Better selecting by values of index, columns, it is same ouput if not duplicated `index/columns` values use [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)/[`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
for row in DF.index:
    for col in DF.columns:
        print(DF.at[row, col])
        #print(DF.loc[row, col])
```

BUT if possible use some vectorized solution the best is avoid looping.

Comment: Thank you very much, why should I avoid using range and len ?

Comment: @TourEiffel - if no duplicates in index/ columns yes.

Comment: How do I display column name before the first line of the DF ?

Answer (score 0):

A nice option might be to [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and use a single loop:

```
for (row, col), value in df.stack().items():
    print(row, col, value)
```

Example:

```
i A 0
i B 1
i C 2
j A 3
j B 4
j C 5
k A 6
k B 7
k C 8
```

used input:

```
   A  B  C
i  0  1  2
j  3  4  5
k  6  7  8
```